# Managing timer intervals using millis at random intervals

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, rtc, millis

I am doing a project which needs to meet the following specifications.

> On receiving an SMS arduino will start switching 1st relay on after some
>   time duration(say 30 Seconds) relay 1 will be turned off and it will now turn on 2nd relay for (say 20seconds) so on 1>2>3>4.

The problem im facing is managing the time intervals between the switching process,i did think of using millis() i.e **(currentMillis-previousMillisx>Intervalx)** as in blinkWithoutDelay ,how ever this will work only once as i dont not know when will the next SMS come to the system ,if the user decides to send the message after 1hour currentMillis-previousMillisx will always return true so i cannot keep the motor on for (Say 30 seconds) and same will happen with all 4 cases.

If there is any alternative logic for this problem please suggest me or can i just add RTC for my project to manage time easily

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need a sort of tracking for your active relay, don't you? So you just have to reset that tracking variable and the previousMillis variables and you are done.

Some code (note: untested and moreover I don't know how you are receiving the SMS)

```
// The intervals for the different relays
const byte Intervals[] = {30, 20, 10, 5};

// The current state. 0 means relay 1 on, 
// 1 means relay 2 on, 2->3 and 3->4, while
// 4 means no relay activated
byte currentState = 4;

unsigned long previousMillis;


void loop()
{
    if (received_sms)
    {
        currentState = 0;
        previousMillis = millis();
        digitalWrite(RELAY1, HIGH);
        // Maybe turn off all the other relays?
    }

    if (currentState < 4)
    { // Active state: check if we should advance
        unsigned long currentInterval = ((unsigned long)Intervals[currentState])*1000;
        while ((millis() - previousMillis) >= currentInterval)
        { // Advance to the next step
            switch(currentState)
            {
                case 0: // Advance from state 0 to 1
                    digitalWrite(RELAY1, LOW);
                    digitalWrite(RELAY2, HIGH);
                    // Maybe turn off all the other relays?
                    previousMillis += currentInterval;
                    currentState = 1;
                    break;
                ...
                // cases 1, 2, 3
                ...
                default:
                    // It should never reach this
                    previousMillis = millis();
                    currentState = 4;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: (a) Using a `switch`/`case` statement to select which relay to work on, with four blocks of nearly identical code (instead of using an array with pin numbers, and a single block of code) is odious.  (b) Although the `while`   (in the `if (currentState < 4)` block) works ok, it functions as an `if` statement and IMO should be written as such.

Comment: if(received_sms){} block made my day " previousMillis=millis()" inside that will now allow me to get the offset from the point i recieved the SMS ,,Thanks You

Comment: @jwpat7 I agree that if the code is nearly identical the `switch/case` can be rewritten in a more concise form, but often (almost always) you have to do something else in the cases (and that's why when dealing with simple - and complex - state machines my mind always implements it as `switch/case`). In this case, however, this could be simplified. The while, however, is much more secure than the if. Since `previousMillis` is not reset to `millis()` but just incremented (more precise), if some function blocks the thread for too much time you can lose one step; with the while you can recover it

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand your problem. More specifically,
“currentMillis-previousMillisx will always return true” does not make
sense, as it is not a boolean expression (it's `unsigned long`).

Anyway, the technique shown in blinkWithoutDelay is the way to go. Here
is my (untested) version:

```c++
const int relay_count = 4;  // we have 4 relays
const int relay_pins[relay_count] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
const unsigned long durations[relay_count] = {30000, 20000, 15000, 10000};
bool sms_received();  // you implement this one

void loop()
{
    static int current_relay = -1;  // meaning: no active relay
    static unsigned long last_switch;
    unsigned long now = millis();

    // If no relay is active, wait for an SMS.
    if (current_relay == -1) {
        if (sms_received()) {
            // Switch on first relay.
            current_relay = 0;
            digitalWrite(relay_pins[current_relay], HIGH);
            last_switch = now;
        }
    }

    // Otherwise, switch relays when it is time to do so.
    else if (now - last_switch >= durations[current_relay]) {
        digitalWrite(relay_pins[current_relay], LOW);
        if (++current_relay == relay_count) {
            current_relay = -1;  // no active relay
        } else {
            digitalWrite(relay_pins[current_relay], HIGH);
            last_switch = now;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, you did not specify what should happen if you receive an SMS while
one of the relays is active. I assume the SMS are only acknowledged when
no relay is active. Otherwise you would have to change the code.

Answer (score -1):

You could use timer interrupts. I've (successfully) used the [TimerOne](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimerOne) library. There are countless other libraries that allow you to use timer interrupts easily. "Start" the timer when you receive the SMS message. You could use a pair of boolean flags to keep track of the two relays with one timer.

Comment: i am now using TimerOne ,,,it however is not the best method and not very safe

Comment: @Lokanath I'm curious. Why do you say that?

Comment: Interrupts are good but how ever you cannot pass values to the ISR,as far as i know ISR will execute when the timerExpires and uses the values of variables current values at the expiry point inside ISR which i totally cannot control which makes program unpredictable

Comment: @Lokanath You could use global variables and declare them as 'volatile'. This tells the compiler to reload the variable every time you reference it as opposed to using a copy from a register.

Comment: ya you are right,,,usage of interrupts needs more than beginners knowledge,,,if you know how to use it you can manage them